# small rootless SMTP server for linux?

Tags: linux, smtp

Is there a SMTP server that can start on localhost without root privileges? Postfix and sendmail both require root to start.

Update: To clarify both Postfix and sendmail require root to start even if port is changed to above 1024.

Comment: What fails when you try to start Postfix on a high port?  You'd need to turn off the chrooting, and make sure everything that Postfix needs is owned by your user, but with enough custom config it should be doable.  Useless, but doable.

Comment: Postfix source code specifically requires superuser to start daemon and smtp so not possible.

Comment: After some research solution is to install exim, change SMTP port number, chown exim spool directory for the required user, then modify exim source code to remove the requirement for root and chowns.

Comment: Can you narrow it down a bit?  "Postfix source code" is a pretty big haystack.

Comment: src/postfix/master.c look for "msg_fatal("the master command is reserved for the superuser");". This message is also present in other locations in postfix source code

Answer (score 5):

I can recommend Haraka - you can use it as non-root on a high port without modifying the source code.

Disclaimer: I wrote Haraka.

Comment: [Haraka](http://haraka.github.com/) is a pleasant alternative to Postfix.  Great work.

Answer (score 3):

Root privileges are required to listen on ports <1024. Usage of these ports is restricted to root or a user running with the CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE privilege (which requires root to configure).

Your other option is to run a server on a port >1024.

Comment: Postfix/Sendmail still require root to start on port > 1024

Answer (score 1):

After some research solution is to install exim, change SMTP port number, chown exim spool directory for the required user, then modify exim source code to remove the requirement for root and chowns.

Answer (score 0):

- I have `postfix` running rootless in a `podman` container:

[image: Bare Metal processes]

- The `root` process inside the container appears as user `ubuntu` on bare metal:

[image: Inside the Postfix container]

- Bind to a port above `1024` (so more capabilities can be dropped) & use `slirp4netns` for networking so ip addresses are logged correctly:

[image: Mail sending rootlessly]